# Is reactjs (or nextjs) suitable for classic website?

Tags: php, reactjs, laravel, express, next.js

Is reactjs (or nextjs) suitable for classic website? I will develop website for kindergarten. Is it good or bad idea to go with react? Of course as multiple page app... Or will be better idea to use PHP (with laravel)? I don't know PHP much (And laravel). On the other side I know reactjs+nextjs+expressjs and I want to improve in it, so i think it could be good idea to use this project for learning and training...

What do you think? Should I use rather reactjs+nextjs+expressjs or PHP+Laravel?

Thanks for every opinion! :)

PS: In my country is VPS very cheap, so it is not problem to use expressjs (nodejs) for kindergarten website...

Comment: That's opinion-based

Answer (score 1):

You could also go with `next export`, and serve the website via cdn for example.

Read more at https://nextjs.org/docs/advanced-features/static-html-export

I would go with nextjs anyways, it’s opinionaited anyways whichever someone recommends, and you want to code in that and learn that, so why not.